# is there any method to create table in Amazon redshift (shifting from RDS or creating via cralwer)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I want to transfer my Data from R.D.S to Red-shift via Amazon GLUE
1 added a connection for R.D.S and ran a crawler which created the schema of my R.D.S into Amazon GLUE 
Now i have a lot of tables, How can i transfers this schema or all tables in Red-shift

I followed a Tutorial but in that he already had a table in Red-shift so he was using 2nd crawler to get schema, and then performing E.T.L job on source and target.

But in my case i have a lot of tables and i cant create each one of them

Please help I am new on Amazon Web services

Comment: Have you tried using DMS? that works much more easily.

Comment: yes try DMS instead of Glue.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use AWS Data Pipeline to copy your data from your RDS storage to Redshift.  [There is already an article from AWS providing you with the steps](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-copy-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was during Creation of Redshift it made a default database with Name dev in it and i didnt know about that.
To create Tables in Redshift, Just During ETL job, (in target table selection window), select CREATE TABLE  and Mention that DEV Database in required field.It will create a table with same name as source's table but it will append source name with that table
For Example if customer is Your database and ID is table, then in REDSHIFT it will create table Customer_ID

and One thing  GLUE is much more simple that DMS or any other service.